# Can cookie names start with a numerical digit?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, cookies

Just a quick question, can a cookie name begin with a number (or only contain numerical digits)?

I can't find anything in the official specs that specifically says it's not allowed, but just wondering if it would cause any problems, both in browsers and when dealing with them in C# code (using MVC5):

- `123cookie` ?
- `123456` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to mozilla reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#Directives

`A <cookie-name> can be any US-ASCII characters except control characters (CTLs), spaces, or tabs. It also must not contain a separator character like the following: ( ) < > @ , ; : \ " /  [ ] ? = { }`

Therefore yes, you are allowed to have the cookies you described according to that reference - which makes sense given that the name is taken as a String-.

Since the `Set Cookie` is a function available in all browsers, it's safe to assume it will apply to most if not all major browsers.